# Is there any connection between Hanuman of Ramayana and the monkey King who journeyed to the west?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman

Is there any truth in saying they are the same.Even though both stories are completely different?
Monkey king was an important part of a Chinese folk story. He was a demi God and he was an immortal.
This is the story
Monkey King is based on a true story of a famous monk, Xuan Zang of the Chinese Tang Dynasty (602-664). ... He was, according to the story, born out of a rock, fertilized by the grace of Heaven and Earth. Being extremely intelligent, he has learned all the magic tricks and gongfu from an immortal Taoist master.

Comment: You need to elaborate  more about "Monkey King" you mentioned, aslo state  that from where you come across the story  of this monkey king?

Comment: Yes the origin of Monkey King is from Hanuman, just like the nowadays famous laughing Buddha is in reality a Chinese version of Kubera(also called goblin with gold in European folklore). China is good in copy-paste and even copied Vedic Vastu Shastra and repackaged as Feng Shui.